# In Facade.php line 258: A facade root has not been set

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, multi-tenant, laravel-permission, laravel-facade

I was working on my Laravel project and suddenly got this error:

```
In Facade.php line 258:
A facade root has not been set.
```

My last command is `php artisan make:migration ...`
It ran successfully

Here is the file causing the exception

`vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php`

```
if (! $instance) {
    throw new RuntimeException('A facade root has not been set.'); // Here
}
```

I tried deleting the `vendor` folder and running `composer install`. It didn't help.

- PHP 8.0.13
- Laravel 8.73.2

Packages being used:

```
  "require": {
    "php": "^8.0",
    "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^2.0",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.0.1",
    "lanin/laravel-api-debugger": "^4.0", //
    "laravel/framework": "^8.65",
    "laravel/sanctum": "^2.11",
    "laravel/tinker": "^2.5",
    "laravel/ui": "^3.3",
    "nwidart/laravel-modules": "^8.2", //
    "spatie/laravel-permission": "^5.4", //
    "stancl/tenancy": "^3.4" //
  },
  "require-dev": {
    "barryvdh/laravel-debugbar": "^3.6", //
    "facade/ignition": "^2.5",
    "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.1",
    "laravel/sail": "^1.0.1",
    "mockery/mockery": "^1.4.4",
    "nunomaduro/collision": "^5.10",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.5.10"
  },
```

Comment: The file causing the exception is not the laravel facade file . You must be using a wrongly coded facade somewhere. You should check the stack trace to try and determine what that facade actually is